# Azure Application Gateway- Redirect traffic to an external site without the URL changing

Tags: azure, redirect, url-rewriting, azure-application-gateway

In Azure, I have set up the Application Gateway to redirect traffic from www.mysite.com to www.externalsite.com.

My DNS maps www.mysite.com to the Application Gateway public IP. 
I have two listeners on port 80 and 443 with redirect rules attached.
The rules redirect traffic to www.externalsite.com.

Although the redirect works, I would like to ensure the URL (www.mysite.com) does not change in the address bar after being redirected to the external site.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [HTTP Header rewrite](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/rewrite-http-headers) functionality in Application Gateway V2 SKU and rewrite the Location header in the response header to www.mysite.com at the time of redirection.

Comment: In the Application Gateway, I've added a rewrite condition IF Location in the Response header equals "www.externalsite.com" THEN set Location to "www.mysite.com". However, this doesn't appear to be making a difference. The rule is associated with the redirect rule.

Comment: Are you using external redirection? Can you try listener to listener redirection instead?

Comment: Yes, I'm using an external redirection to a partner site. What's the difference between this and listener to listener redirection?

Comment: Are you just doing a http to https redirection for the external site?

Comment: You can have 2 listener , one for HTTP and another for HTTPS. create listener to listener re-direction and have one rule (HTTPS) to your external site

Comment: I have the following: listener (80) > http to https rule > Listener (443) > redirect rule > external site .

Comment: It sounds like what I want to do here is not possible. Just had a chat with MS Support. Here's their comment: "So to achieve your use case, this would be done with URL masking - but unfortunately we don't support this with our services I'm afraid, a redirect is the only option but masking isn't possible".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207184/discussion-between-msrini-msit-and-confounder).